# Getting records from attributes table in Python console using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I have layer with 5 millions records. I would like to get 1 record from attributes table and show in Python console.

Is it possible?

This does not work:

```
> from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
>     
>     path = r'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/POLSKA/PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA.shp' 
>     lyr = QgsVectorLayer (path, 'PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA.shp', 'ogr')
>     
>     for f in lyr.getFeatures():
>         print(f['ULIC_nazwa'])
```

Comment: The first one or criteria-based ? For the two methods, it's possible yes.

Comment: Firsty i would like to check that and show only 1 but then i would like to show all atrributes. Do you know how to do that? Maybe some code?

Comment: Like in SQL, for example SELECT first record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getFeatures():

```
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ok_ak_riks')[0]
for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    print(f.attributes())
    break
```

[image]

To print a specific attribute:

```
for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    print(f['somefieldname'])
    break
```

Comment: I want to do that without GUI and import layer.

Comment: You can use your PyQgis script outside of Qgis you just need to import some specific qgis library.
Then instead of `QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ok_ak_riks')[0]`
Use :
`path = /path/to/your/layer/ok_ak_riks.shp)`
`lyr = QgsVectorLayer (path, 'layer_name', 'ogr')`

Comment: from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer 

path = r'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/POLSKA/PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA.shp' 
lyr = QgsVectorLayer (path, 'PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA.shp', 'ogr')

for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    print(f['ULIC_nazwa'])

Answer (score 0):

See the QGIS Developer Cookbook section 11.2.3.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html#expressions

The relevant code is

```py
expression = 'Test >= 3'
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expression)

for f in layer.getFeatures(request):
   # f matches the expression
```

Comment: https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/123289601_706185643649787_6908256844568226429_n.png?_nc_cat=106&ccb=2&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=HeW3RhoKsecAX_K5lsO&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.xx&oh=500ff9eec7e3f9d14717d2dcc2bb110b&oe=5FC47030 / it works in QGIS Python console, but in normal console not :/